# Trying to put every number/value in an object into a string array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, jquery-tageditor

I am creating my own JSON object which has info from a table and I am trying to JSON.stringify it so I can throw it into the `"jQuery tagEditor's initialTags` (the tag plugin StackOverflow uses").

Basically the object comes out like this:
`[5094,5651,5812]` - *after I JSON.Stringify it*

and it seems that the tagEditor() uses a string array that comes out like this
`["5094","5651","5812"]` - *which im struggling to get right*

I put the stringified data in a variable and put it in the tagEditors "initialTags" like this:

```
    $('#textareabox').tagEditor({
      initialTags: [Array], 
      delimiter: ', ' /* space and comma */
     });
```

but instead of the results come back as one tag `5651,5812` on button click instead of `5651` `5812` which I'm assuming is because of the way its stringified.

Please assist and thank you.

More code can be provided if need be. This is a Javascript / Jquery / HTML project.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Convert the numbers into strings? Convert the strings into numbers?

Comment: Try `initialTags: [5094,5651,5812].map(String),`

Comment: @VLAZ Sorry maybe I wasnt clear, I am getting back numbers as an object, I need every number to be in its own to come back as multiple strings like: `["5094","5651","5812"]` instead of just a string that looks like `[5094,5651,5812]`

Comment: @User863 Thanks for your response, it works when i hard code the values but for some weird reason, when i put it into as a variable it doesnt. any suggestions?

Comment: @TumiRatefane don't `JSON.stringify()` the array

Comment: @user863 i removed the stringify but take a look at the funtion [here](https://jsfiddle.net/5Ltd6rha/3/) and the output [here](https://unsee.cc/fcca75c9/) . its showing a tag as 1 still. the console log is also added in the screenshots.

Comment: @TumiRatefane `[mccArrayy].map(String)` does not do what you want - you get your array, then *put it in another array*, and stringify the contents of it. So it's a roundabout `newArr = []; newArr.push(mccArrayy.toString())`. If you just want to convert the contents of `mccArrayy` to strings, then call `mccArrayy.map(String)`

Comment: @VLAZ very stupid of me, thank you much. this helped. i marked the other guys .map string as right as i cant mark yours. much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to transform an Array int to Array string ? then you can use it :

`yourArray.map(String)`  -- > ["5094","5651","5812"]

Answer (score 1):

```js
let tags = [5094,5651,5812].map(String);

$('#demo1').tagEditor({
    initialTags: tags,
    delimiter: ', ', /* space and comma */
    placeholder: 'Enter tags ...'
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tag-editor/1.0.20/jquery.tag-editor.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tag-editor/1.0.20/jquery.tag-editor.min.js"></script>

<div id="demo1"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the result array in multiple tags using your delimiter:

```
tag.split(', ')
```